# Can't receive data from AJAX using mamp

Tags: javascript, ajax, mamp

I have some AJAX that I want to run, so I tried downloading MAMP to test it.

There's my JavaScript code

```
const astrosUrl = 'http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json';

function getJSON(url) {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.onload = () => {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            let data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            console.log(data);
        }
    };
    xhr.send;
}

getJSON(astrosUrl);
```

And HTML code

```
<body>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
        <h1>AJAX</h1>
</body>
```

Both files are in htdocs folder

What should I do, to receive data object in my console log?

Comment: xhr.send is a method, why not use fetch?

Comment: Please indicate what you currently output using your setup. It would be helpful if you can create a try-catch block in order to see if there are any errors.